# jwplayer - hide the controls and allow fullscreen?

Tags: jwplayer

The problem is that when I use

```
controls: false
```

I can no longer make the video go to fullscreen (by double clicking it).

There's absolutely nothing in the documentation about this.

Comment: Not really a surprise. Setting controls to false means, "Don't give the visitor any control over this video." It doesn't respond to any clicks, anywhere - it can't be paused, there's no seeking, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

this code work fine for me.

```
controlbar:false
```

Answer (score 0):

This will *only* work in HTML5 mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fullscreen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/11/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
        file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/C4lp6Dtd-el5vTWpr.mp4",
        image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/i8oQD9zd-640.jpg",
        controls: false,
        autostart: true
    });
     jwplayer().onDisplayClick(function() { jwplayer().setFullscreen(true); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: setFullscreen won't work anymore due to security reasons.
http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#resize

Comment: Ah, well, I answered this post in February, so things have changed since then it seems.